# How to setTag Button in ListView

Tags: android, listview, button

I generated Button in row.xml file so it will create number of buttons as same as list item
so I'd like to setTag all of Button in ListView to getTag and retrieve the data from database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you are using the Custom Adapter for your ListView, you will be able to set Tag for each Button inside your Adapter's getView(),

```
@Override
    public View getView(int pos, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

       convertView =    inflaterObject.inflate(R.layout.row,parent,false);
       Button tagButton=(Button)convertView.findviewbyId(R.id.buttonID);
       tagButton.setTag(pos);

      //To fetch the button Tag

      Log.i("Button Tab at Pos "+pos,tagButton.getTag()+"");

}
```

Comment: sry i'm newbie for android

<code>for(InQueueAdapter q:queue) {
   map = new HashMap<String, String>();
   map.put("id", Integer.toString(q.getID()));
   map.put("amount",q.getAm());
   
   mylist.add(map);
   
  }

  SimpleAdapter ms = new SimpleAdapter(this, mylist, R.layout.data_row
    , new String[] {"id","amount"}, new int[] {R.id.idCell,R.id.amountCell});
  list.setAdapter(ms); <code>

where should i put it in

Comment: Can you edit your question and add the code for SimpleAdapter?